# OpenFrameworks file not found issue

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ipad, openframeworks

I get the following error when trying to run an app from Github on my Ipad.

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'ip/NetworkingUtils.h' file not found

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnmDM.png)

I see that this file exists on my harddrive when I do a search, but I have no idea how to rectify the issue. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: welp... I guess you need to add it to the header searchpaths or use a cflag to have '-Iyour/path/to/includedir'

Comment: @Martinukai At first glance it looks like a liboscpack header file: double check if ofxOSC is added to your project and if it works on IOS

Comment: Thanks for the tips. As it turns out I made some settings changes without changing any code and the error disappeared. It was a connectivity settings issue between ipad and mac I think.